# Perl Adding String in Middle of another String

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, what's the best way to turn this string:

7705554200-4299

into

7705554200-7705554299

I know how to grab the first 6 digits but not sure how to insert them after the hyphen.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $num = '7705554200-4299';

# Check to see number is a range
if ($num =~ /-/)
{
  # Pull area code and exchange
  my $extract = substr($num, 0, 6);
  print "Area code + exchange: $extract\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $num = '7704814200-4299';

# Check to see if it is a range
if ($num =~ /-/)
{
  # Pull area code and exchange
  my $extract = substr($num, 0, 6);
  print "Extracted this: $extract\n";

  $num =~ s/-/-$extract/;
  print $num;

}
```

Comment: While you can do this in a regex, you found a solution that allowed you to print out debug information and is probably easier to maintain. Congrats! Not every solution should be done with a regex!  (Sometimes it's unavoidable, but not this time.)

Comment: To support comment by Tanktalus (beat me to it), this is a nice solution. Crystal clear and nicely maintable. Most of the time there are alternatives to complex regex and they are usually better code.

Comment: Regex here isn't all that hard (I still prefer what you did), and for your reference: `$num =~ s/(\d{6})\d*-\K/$1/`. The only trick is `\K`, a particular form of the _postive lookbehind_.  These patterns only _assert_ that something is there, without consuming it.  The `\K` also 'frees' everything matched before it so that the substitution won't touch it. So we don't have to retype it.  See [`this in perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

Comment: In fact `\K` is in [Extended Patterns in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns), under "_Lookaround assertions_"

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't really need the full power of regular expression pattern matching, you can use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) and the fourth parameter of [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) to insert some characters immediately after the hyphen:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num = '7705554200-4299';
substr($num, index($num, '-') + 1, 0, substr($num, 0, 6));
print "$num\n";
```

You can also use `substr` as an lvalue, but personally, I find that version to be more obtuse:

```
substr($num, index($num, '-') + 1, 0) = substr($num, 0, 6);
```

Result:

```
7705554200-7705554299
```